# Coin Change Problem(Greedy Algorithm)

Tags: algorithms, optimization, greedy-algorithms, coin-change

In Coin Change Problem, if the ratio of Coin Value ($\frac{Coin_(i+1)}{coin(i)}$) is always increasing then we can use Greedy Algorithm?

Example- $(1,3,4)$ are denominations of coin.
If I want to pay $Rs.6$ then the smallest coin set would be $(3,3)$.
This solution set cannot be found by greedy Algorithm because it does not satisfy $(\frac{4}{3} > \frac{3}{1})$.

Comment: "Coin change .... greedy ..." -- \*Vader NOOOOoooo\*

Comment: Try simultaneously proving your claim and looking for a counterexample. Get back to us if you haven't succeeded after trying for a few hours.

Comment: By the way, the [Wikipedia article on the problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem) is far from good, but it *does* contain some information.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I did try but count not prove it.Can you help.

Answer (score 4):

For the set of coins (2,3,11). $\frac{3}{2}<\frac{11}{3}$ so by your assumption we can be greedy here. Consider the value of 23. The greedy strategy would involve first taking 2 11 cent coins to give us 22 cents. Then there is nowhere left to go, we cant possibly get to 23 from here. We do have a solution though with $(0,4,1)$

Answer (score 0):

Check out Beck, *"How to Change Coins, M&M's, or Chicken Nuggets: The Linear Diophantine Problem of Frobenius"*, pp. 6-74 in *Resources for Teaching Discrete Mathematics:               Classroom Projects, History Modules, and Articles* (MAA, 2009). Necessary and sufficient conditions for the greedy algorithm to work are given by Pearson, [*"A Polynomial-time Algorithm for the Change-Making Problem"*](https://hdl.handle.net/1813/6219), TR94-1433, Department of Computer Science, Cornell (1994). They are *much* more complicated to check than your proposal.

Answer (score -2):

Say, set of `coin = {1, 10, 25}`

It doesn't satisfy `25/10 > 10/1` But still can be solved by greedy algorithm.

Now, say `X` is any set of coins in increasing order. Then, for all `a` and `b` in `X` where `a < b`, if `2*a <= b` satisfies, It will be solvable with greedy algorithm.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question *and* contains an unproven claim (last line).